# Excel: Name sheet tab from cell value in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I can successfully name my sheet tab based on a cell reference in the same sheet with the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Set Target = Range("A1")
    If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo Badname
    ActiveSheet.Name = Left(Target, 31)
    Exit Sub
Badname:
    MsgBox "Please revise the entry in A1." & Chr(13) _
    & "It appears to contain one or more " & Chr(13) _
    & "illegal characters." & Chr(13)
    Range("A1").Activate
End Sub
```

However, I am struggling to change the sheet tab based on a cell reference in the title sheet. I have tried simply replacing the range with the reference from the desired sheet, `Range("Keywords!A1")`, but this does not seem to work.

Any suggestions to get around this would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this to reference another worksheet

```
Worksheets("Keywords").Range("A1").Value
```

Comment: Just to add further context, you can use `Sheets` as well. [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/frice/2007/12/05/excels-worksheets-and-sheets-collection-whats-the-difference/) explains the difference quite well. For this example though it doesn't matter.